# Screen Capture and Visual Studio C# Express?

Tags: c#, screenshot

I have tried "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/ScreenMonitor.aspx?msg=3717430#xx3717430xx" to capture all things at working desktop, its good. But I saw that whenever I open CSExpress 2010 (Visual Studio Express) for my programming environment this utility capture as BLACK image, so whats the issue with it.

Screen like it : [image]

Please let me know.

Thanks,
Laxmilal

Comment: Wow, a CodeProject-StackOverflow cross-post. Is there a meta API for such tasks?

Comment: I think, you should capture alpha blended windows as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is tied into the VS2010 usage of WPF, combined with WPFs ability to hook into hardware GPU if it wants. And presumably your screen capture tool isn't loving the way your video driver handles that.